# Web crawling/scraping a list of all files (which are publicly available) instead of going via 5 clocks from home page for each file

Tags: python, firefox-extensions, browser-addons, web-crawler, screen-scraping

#### Summary of the problem

I am trying to create a list (and potentially download) of all files (100s) from the following address: https://eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy

This is something I would use for my work on a weekly basis to identify changes or new items on the site.

The 5 clicks to do this manually for each file are as follows:

- https://eba.europa.eu/
- https://eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy
- https://eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/accounting-and-auditing
- https://eba.europa.eu/regulation-and-policy/accounting-and-auditing/rts-on-methods-of-prudential-consolidation
- https://eba.europa.eu/sites/default/documents/files/documents/10180/2019694/3b8e5188-f7e3-4d11-b9ae-256e47d61e4b/Consultation%20Paper%20on%20RTS%20on%20methods%20of%20prudential%20consolidation%20%28EBA-CP-2017-20%29.pdf

#### Research

I have searched for code and plugins.

#### What I’ve tried

I have tried using multiple plugins via Firefox and Google Chrome and also Python scripts, however, I have only been successful at downloading files and cannot generate a list of files with their attributes (where available, blank if not) e.g. topic, status, date, a link to the file etc.

I have seen this being done by a software developer so I know it can be done. This is something I would be so grateful for if you can help, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: If you can download the files, you could compare their contents for detecting changes.

Answer (score 1):

Wget and httrack can be used to perform website strips for given files, extensions, link depths, etc.
I only use wget for this purpose, though not strictly a web scraper.

```
wget -P [download dir] -pkr -ln [URL] - Download URL and recurse pages to link depth n and convert all links to relative filesystem.

wget -r -l4 -spider -D [URLs] [URL] - Recursively spider URL to link depth 4 restricting recursion to listed URLs.
```

There are some good wget guides online.

httrack is installed from Debian or Debian-based repos.